# Is it possible to have the center div fill to the right when the right div is empty?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to rebuild our website's layout and I found this great [article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail) on the holy grail of div+css layouts.  I was able to successfully recreate the layout on my own site.  I did run into one problem and that is what I need help fixing now.

Is it possible to modify this css below to cause the center div to fill all the way to the right edge of the container when the right div contains no markup?  I have some pages that have right side content and some do not.

Here is the code from http://www.alistapart.com/d/holygrail/example_3.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>The Holy Grail of Layouts: Example #3: A List Apart</title>
    <style type="text/css">
 
        /*
 
 The Essential Code 
 
*/
 
        body {
            min-width: 630px;         /* 2 x (LC fullwidth + CC padding) + RC fullwidth */
        }
 
        #container {
            padding-left: 200px;      /* LC fullwidth */
            padding-right: 190px;     /* RC fullwidth + CC padding */
        }
        
        #container .column {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
        }
        
        #center {
            padding: 10px 20px;       /* CC padding */
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        #left {
            width: 180px;             /* LC width */
            padding: 0 10px;          /* LC padding */
            right: 240px;             /* LC fullwidth + CC padding */
            margin-left: -100%;
        }
        
        #right {
            width: 130px;             /* RC width */
            padding: 0 10px;          /* RC padding */
            margin-right: -100%;
        }
        
        #footer {
            clear: both;
        }
        
        /*
 
 IE Fix 
 
*/
        * html #left {
            left: 150px;              /* RC fullwidth */
        }
 
        /*
 
 Equal-height Columns 
 
*/
 
        #container {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
 
        #container .column {
            padding-bottom: 1001em;     /* X + padding-bottom */
            margin-bottom: -1000em;     /* X */
        }
 
        /*
 
 Footer Fix 
 
*/
 
        * html body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        * html #footer-wrapper {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            padding-bottom: 10010px;
            margin-bottom: -10000px;
            background: #FFF;         /*
 
 Same as body background 
 
*/
        }
 
        /*
 
 Just for Looks 
 
*/
 
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #FFF;
        }
 
        #header, #footer {
            font-size: large;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0.3em 0;
            background: #999;
        }
 
        #left {
            background: #66F;
        }
 
        #center {
            background: #DDD;
        }
 
        #right {
            background: #F66;
        }
 
        #container .column {
            padding-top: 1em;
            text-align: justify;
        }
 
    </style>
</head>
 
<body>
 
    <div id="header">This is the header.</div>
 
    <div id="container">
 
        <div id="center" class="column">
            <h1>This is the main content.</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="left" class="column">
            <h2>This is the left sidebar.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="right" class="column">
            <h2>This is the right sidebar.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
        </div>
 
    </div>
 
    <div id="footer-wrapper">
        <div id="footer">This is the footer.</div>
    </div>
 
</body>
 
</html>
```

---

### Update

I tried the javascript suggested and it did not improve the layout.  This was executing on .Ready().

```
if ($('#right').html() == "") {
    $('#center').width('100%');
    $('#right').width(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript to accomplish this.

Your JavaScript onload code should look like this:

1. Check to see whether the right div has any content in it
2. If not, set the right div's width to 0 and the center div's width to its starting with + the right div's starting width.

   if (document.getElementById("rightDiv").innerHTML == "")
   {
       document.getElementById("centerDiv").style.width = '500px'; // change 500 to whatever the center width + right width would be, or you can calculate this dynamically if necessary

   ```
   document.getElementById("rightDiv").style.width = '0px;' // or set it to display: none, perhaps
   ```

   }

Comment: This did not work.  I still get an empty right side div with the original width.